# Can I use SE to ask for advice?

Tags: discussion

I'm a WebForms developer and am just starting to get into MVC.  I'd like to become acquainted with all of the latest technologies, best practices, and architecture design as they pertain to MVC and browser UI.  Asking advice from high-rep users seems like a great place to start, but I'm afraid such a question would just get closed as "not constructive".  As a side note, one thing I'll never understand is how nearly all of the most upvoted questions on SE are nearly all closed as being not constructive, off-topic, or some other reason.  It seems like SE could really benefit by permitting constructive subjectivity.

Answer (score 13):

No, SE is not a place to just come and ask for general advice.

The fact that these types of questions are *popular* doesn't mean that they're appropriate for the site, or that they're particularly useful.  They're *entertaining* for a lot of people (hence the votes), but these types of questions largely result in very poor quality contributions.  (This is of course hard for you to observe, because for every highly upvoted question that has 1-2 decent answers there are 10 more deleted posts full of extremely low quality contributions.)

Answer (score 2):

One of our goals for our questions and answers is that future users can gain utility from these questions/answers after the fact.

When you have an ambiguous question, which lends itself to having ambiguously correct answers, it's troublesome, because future visitors won't know what to expect when visiting that question from Google.

It's a lot more helpful when I can read a question, and know that if this question is answered sufficiently, then my own needs should also be met by whatever the answer is.  Subjective questions don't lend themselves very well to this need-meeting paradigm, so we close them.

It's really frustrating to stumble into some Q/A forum site while I'm searching for solutions to my problem, and to have a bunch of content that doesn't really solve my problem.

---

If you want to ask a question about best practices, that's fine so long as you know specifically what you're looking for.  Many best practices are documented somewhere, and agreed upon, and even the ones that aren't agreed upon are still somehow documented.

Comment: Well that is too bad.  A question for guidance can save one hours of spinning down a whole.  But I understand the need to have black and white/simple syntax questions so that trollers can earn badges.  I just didn't realize the secondary purpose of the site was a self esteem builder.